# What is the minimum Xcode version to be able to submit for iTunes Connect?

Tags: xcode

It's been a while since I've used my Mac and it's OS X and Xcode is out of date. Since it's an old machine (Mid-2012) MackBook Pro, I was wondering which are minimum versions of updates I should get to be able to submit to iTunes Connect.

I rather not to go latest, especially on OS, since it will make my machine slower than it is now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best way to know about whether a build can be submitted to App Store or not can be found out by applying Validate option on the generated Archive.

Open Organizer, Select your Archive, Select Validate option... Xcode would tell accordingly whether your app can be submitted or not.

**EDIT**

It also depends on the iOS version you want to support. You would need latest Xcode for newer iOS versions.